# Rock Paper Scissor ending loop after 5 wins for either user

Tags: java

I was hoping I could receive some help.  For some reason I cant get this to work.  I am trying to end the loop after one of the users gets 5 wins.  For some reason I can keep an error message.  I can get the game to record a score after each game played but, I cant get it to end after 5 wins.  Can someone help?

```
package rockpaperscissors;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author gmc72
 */
public class RockPaperScissors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userWin = 0;
    int userLoss = 0;
    int user2Win = 0;
    int user2Loss = 0;
    int draw = 0;


    while (true) {
        System.out.println("User: Wins " + userWin + " / Loss: " + userLoss);
        System.out.println("User2: Wins " + user2Win + " / Loss: " + user2Loss);
        System.out.println("Draw: " + draw);
        System.out.print("\nChoose scissors(0), rock(1), paper(2), or -1 to end the game: ");
        int user = input.nextInt();
        int user2 = input.nextInt ();

        while (winner < 5) {

            if (user == 0 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose rock. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 0 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose paper. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose scissors. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose paper. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose scissors. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose rock. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 0 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose scissors. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose rock. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose paper. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == -1) {
                break;
            }
        if (userWin == 5) || (user2Win == 5) {
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Comment: Where are you modifying the value of `winner` variable?

Comment: Post the error message.  Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The fact that you didn't bother to complete the 2-minute site tour looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable `userWin` instead of your undeclared `winner` inside the loop condition:
`while (userWin < 5 && user2Win < 5)`

---

This way after user or user 2 won 5 times, your loop will exit.

---

Also remove this part:

```
if (userWin == 5) ||(user2Win == 5) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i fixed your code notice that what you need to do is proceed to ask for user input until one of the users won atleaset 5 times

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userWin = 0;
    int userLoss = 0;
    int user2Win = 0;
    int user2Loss = 0;
    int draw = 0;


        System.out.println("User: Wins " + userWin + " / Loss: " + userLoss);
        System.out.println("User2: Wins " + user2Win + " / Loss: " + user2Loss);
        System.out.println("Draw: " + draw);
        System.out.print("\nChoose scissors(0), rock(1), paper(2), or -1 to end the game: ");


        while (userWin < 5 && user2Win < 5) { // Reapet asking untils someone won 5 times
            int user = input.nextInt();
            int user2 = input.nextInt();
            if (user == 0 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose rock. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 0 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose paper. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose scissors. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose paper. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose scissors. User2 wins!");
                user2Win++;
                userLoss++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose rock. You win!");
                userWin++;
                user2Loss++;
            } else if (user == 0 && user2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("User chose scissors. User2 chose scissors. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == 1 && user2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("User chose rock. User2 chose rock. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == 2 && user2 == 2) {
                System.out.println("User chose paper. User2 chose paper. Its a draw!");
                draw++;
            } else if (user == -1) {
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("\nThanks for playing!");

}
```

}